# How to enlarge the x, y or z axis of a 3d diagramm in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

How can I set the diagramm to enlarge(!) and show all the ticks in one or more of the axis? See picture below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ys = np.linspace(0, 30, 30)
xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, X * Y)
plt.show()
```

I don't want square axis. I guess that the default plots square axis, i.e. the axis x, y, and z have all the same length. The default looks like the following (without the red arrow!).

[image]

I need to "enlarge",  "stretch" or "scale"  (sorry, I don't know how it is called) the axis. For example, when the x, y axis have 30x30 values, then it is ok to have square axies like the default figuer above or the next first figure. But if they have 30x10 or 10x30 values, I would like to plot them like the next second and third figure respectively:

[image]

The suggested `plt.figure(figsize=(6,2))` or `plt.figure(figsize=(2,6))` has no good results for 3d diagramms. The following is not what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by enlarge? Do you want a larger figure and thus space for additional tick marks? In that case you could set the ´figsize´ argument of the ´plt.figure´ call.

Comment: I need to stretch the axis. The default of the figure is a square and if I set the `figsize` we get the square wider or taller. This is not what I need. I need to strecht one axis. See the update of my question.

Comment: So you want to change the aspect ratio(s)?

Comment: @tcaswell: Sorry, I'm not sure what it is called. Maybe it is aspect ratio. I've updated my question with figures to texplain what I need.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: See my update comments on why `figsize` doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.